# Creación de un componente de JavaFX para cargarlo en Scene Builder con un jar externo

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy intentando crear un `ComboBox` para JavaFX que pueda ser cargado en Scene Builder y que contenga un jar donde se encuentra el código para acceder a base de datos y recuperar según la consulta indicada los elementos a mostrar.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que al cargar el nuevo componente en Scene Builder da un fallo pues no encuentra las clases definidas en el jar mostrando el siguiente mensaje de error al consultar JAR Analysis Report:

```
  Exception for: customcontrolexample/CustomControl.class
  java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/Printer
  at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:109)
  at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
  at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
```

Al ver el contenido del jar que creo compruebo que no carga el jar del código con el que me conecto a base de datos.

¿Cómo se puede generar desde Eclipse un jar de un proyecto que hace referencia a otro fichero jar?

Answer (score 1):

Un jar usualmente se genera solo con sus clases y recursos. Las dependencias del jar (otros jar) se deberán agregar manualmente al proyecto principal que utilizará todos los jar. La figura sería de esta manera:

- jar A se conecta a base de datos
- jar B provee un `ComboBox` y requiere de jar A para funcionar
- jar C es la aplicación principal y requiere de jar B para mostrar un `ComboBox`. Para que funcione completamente, jar C también requiere de jar A por la dependencia que tiene jar B sobre jar A.

Si quieres "evitar" (porque no lo puedes evitar) incluir tantas dependencias a tu proyecto, lo que puedes hacer es crear fat jars o uber jars. Este tipo de jars son jars gordos que contienen todas sus dependencias embebidas en el. Se le llama jar gordo porque su peso en KB incrementa significativamente por tener embebidos los otros jars de los que depende. Para lograr esto, hay herramientas vía maven o gradle que lo resuelven por ti.